# How to upgrade airflow?

Tags: airflow

There seems to be no proper documentation about upgrading airflow. The [Upgrading Airflow to a newer version](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/installation/upgrading.html) page only talks about upgrading the database. So what is the proper way of upgrading airflow?

Is it just upgrading the python packages to the newest versions? Or should I use the same venv and install the newer airflow version completely from scratch? Or is it something else altogether?

I'm guessing doing the database upgrade would be the final step followed by one of these steps.

Comment: If your airflow running on docker container and version is not too different, then stop existing container and start new container (with preserve volume, network mounting) will be Okay, It's not, I think there is no nice way to upgrade framework, you may do upgrade process totally manually from starting new version server and copying dags and test with refer migration guide for each version changes.

Comment: I'm not running airflow on docker, so I don't think this is an option

Comment: set up new airflow using virtualenv to separate existing python environment but with same db and dags, logs, etc path, than migrate dags one by one (turn off/on).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was also struggling with upgrading airflow for minor versions and didn't feel like I found a good answer in the docs. I think I have the right approach after looking back at how I installed airflow in the first place.

- If you followed the [guide to run airflow locally](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/local.html) you'll want to change the value for `AIRFLOW_VERSION` in the commands to your desired version.
- If you followed the [guide to run airflow on docker](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html), then you'll want to fetch the latest docker-compose.yaml. The command on the site always has the latest version. Then re-run `docker compose up`.

You can confirm you have the right version by running `airflow version`. I run airflow via docker so the docker steps work for me, I imagine the local steps should be about the same.

Comment: Yes, I did exactly this. Sorry I forgot I had asked this question, could have save you some time. I'll add add a few more details in form of another answer. Thanks again

Comment: Viv, I have facing same issue. but the currently airflow hosted on Kubernetes cluster and installed using Helm charts. There is no any proper documentation for the airflow version upgrade on kubernetes. If you get chance or you did work around then please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

Adding to Vivian's answer -
I had installed airflow from [PyPi](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.3.0/installation/installing-from-pypi.html) and was upgrading from 2.2.4 to 2.3.0.

To upgrade airflow,

1. I installed the new version of airflow in the same virtual environment as 2.2.4 (using [this](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.3.0/installation/installing-from-pypi.html#upgrading-airflow-with-providers)).
2. Upgraded the database using `airflow db upgrade`. More details [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.3.0/installation/upgrading.html).
3. You might have to manually upgrade providers using `pip install packagename -U`

After this, when I started Airflow, I got an error related to some missing conf. Airflow wanted the newest version of `airflow.cfg`, but I had the older version. To fix this,

1. Renamed my `airflow.cfg` to `airflowbackup.cfg`. This is done so that airflow will make a new `airflow.cfg` on start up when it sees that there is no config file.
2. Compared `airflowbackup.cfg` with the 2.2.4 config to find out all the fields I had changed.
3. Manually made those same changes in the newly made `airflow.cfg`

For Helm installations - update the helm chart to the newer version if present, update the airflow version in the chart and apply it.